# How can I solve delay in showing count down timer(JLabel) in Swing JPanel

Tags: java, swing, timer, event-dispatch-thread, cardlayout

I've implemented a count down timer(in function) which updates a label in swing panel every second this is the code:

```
public void DefineTimer()
    {
    Action updateClockAction = new AbstractAction() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                         JPanelMainGame.this.jLabelSeconds.setText(Integer.toString(JPanelMainGame.this.m_TimerTotalSeconds));
                         JPanelMainGame.this.jLabelSeconds.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Handwriting", 1, 36));
                         JPanelMainGame.this.jLabelSeconds.setForeground(Color.red);
                         JPanelMainGame.this.jLabelSeconds.setVisible(true);



                        if( JPanelMainGame.this.m_TimerTotalSeconds >0)
                        {
                             JPanelMainGame.this.m_TimerTotalSeconds--;
                        }
                        else if ( JPanelMainGame.this.m_TimerTotalSeconds == 0)
                        {

                            JPanelMainGame.this.m_Timer.stop();
                            JPanelMainGame.this.jLabelSeconds.setText("0");
                            System.out.println("!m_WasGameDecisived: "+!m_WasGameDecisived);

                            JPanelGameApplet gameApplet = (JPanelGameApplet) getTopLevelAncestor();
                            //Checking whether time ended for both players and no solution was recieved

                            if(gameApplet.GetJPanelChooseGame().GetGameType() == eGameType.Net)
                            {


                                gameApplet.GetClinetThread().UpdateServerOfTimeEnded();

                                if (!m_WasGameDecisived)
                                {
                                    // 
                                    System.out.println("Tie - No one had a solution in the given time");

                                    System.out.println("Before send request to solve - Is Socket Closed:"+((JPanelGameApplet) 
                                    gameApplet.GetClinetThread().SendRequestToClosePlayerThreadAndRemoveItFromPlayersOnServer();

                                    ((JPanelGameApplet)getTopLevelAncestor()).GetDJ().stop();
                                    Menu.BrowseTo(PanelMenuNumber.k_ChooseGame, JPanelMainGame.this.getParent());
                                    ((JPanelGameApplet)getTopLevelAncestor()).GetDJ().play(0);

                                }
                            }
                            else if(gameApplet.GetJPanelChooseGame().GetGameType() == eGameType.Single)
                            {
                                JPanelMainGame.this.showPopUpSelectionBar();

                            }

                        }

                       ((JPanelGameApplet)getTopLevelAncestor()).GetNetMainGame().Initialize();

                    }
                };
                m_Timer = new Timer(1000, updateClockAction);
        }
```

Now my problem is in another part of my code when I want to to the following things:

```
case ProtocolMessages.k_StartGame:
                       m_GameApplet.GetJpanelStartNetGame().DefineTimer();
                       m_GameApplet.GetJpanelStartNetGame().GetTimer().start();
                       m_GameApplet.ShowBoardToSolve();
                       Menu.BrowseTo(PanelMenuNumber.k_NetPlayersGameStart,m_GameApplet.GetJPanelNetGameSetting().getParent());
                       m_GameApplet.GetDJ().Next();
                       break;
```

So The problem is when I want to start a game, I'm defining my timer and allocating it,
give it start command and going to the screen that I should see there the timer (`JLabel` updating).
And still although it should be already counting (even before that screen that shows the timer) I still got delay: I get the panel that show the timer, and after about two seconds the `Jlabel` appear and start to count down.
I think that it is because the event dispatch thread that is not updating immediately the `Jlabel` in the time I'm doing `Jlabel.setText()`

Any suggestions of how can I start a game without delay in showing the `Jlabel`?
Thanks

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I would be really glad to hear some advice from you here, I think that my Code is really simple to understand in its own version :)

Comment: *"I think.."* There's no accounting for what people think.  I will only look closely at code after it is compiled in my editor, and I've seen it running (or failing) on-screen.

Comment: Use a SwingWorker, refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889121/forcing-jlabel-to-display-text-before-expensive-operation

Answer (score 2):

Call SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait frm the thread to set the label text.

Comment: Cannot - already in event dispatch thread and therefore exception is thrown that I can't do so from being already in event dispatch thread